# Get subset of array based on values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like the below one

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 3
    [8] => 4
    [9] => 4
    [10] => 4
)
```

Is there any way to get a subset of this array using the values? **So that, if need the subset of value 1, then it has to display**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
)
```

**And if subset of 2 then**

```
Array
(
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 2
)
```

And so on.. I need to preserve the index too.

I searched so many places. But didn't get an answer for this. I wish to avoid the multiple looping for this.

Comment: How do you calculate subset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter an array down to only the elements you're looking for. Set `$subset` to whatever value you're searching for, and it'll return the matching elements, without changing the keys.

```
$subset = 2;

$results = array_filter($array, function ($item) use ($subset) {
    return $item === $subset;
});

print_r($results);
```

> Array
>   (
>       [3] => 2
>       [4] => 2
>   )

See https://eval.in/926983

Comment: Wow.. and that is simply a great solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try array_chunk

```
array_chunk($array,4,true);
```

First parameter array

Second parameter size

Third parameter preserve keys

Comment: Thanks for your time. But this will make the chunks with constant length. In my case, the length could not determine.